# Laravel 5.2 when localize carbon date appear as question marks in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I localized the date with carbon with this code

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Arabic');

$dt = Carbon::now();

$date=$dt->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
echo $date;
dd("   " .$date);
```

I write this code in controller to test

```
  echo $date;
```

-view date correct appear  as الأربعاء 21 ديسمبر 2016

-but when write this code data appear

```
dd("   " .$date); appear as ÇáÃÑÈÚÇÁ 21 ÏíÓãÈÑ 2016"
```

-and when write this code in blade or return blade after localize it appear as question marks.

```
-Date appear as �������� 21 ������ 2016
```

I don't understand  where is the problem and how to solve it.
please any one help me,

Comment: try this library https://github.com/jenssegers/date

Comment: Are you setting the correct HTTP Headers for your character set?

Answer (score 0):

Will I Think The Problem Is In Your Computer Check All Your Local Lang Via This Commend

```
locale -a
```

To Check If You Had The Lang Already Installed In Your PC

Then You Would Do Like

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_SA.utf8');
```

If Doesn't Work You Can Use This Package Otherwise ,

[Data Corbon](https://github.com/jenssegers/date)